# How do change the reply port for a serversocket connection in JAVA

Tags: java, tcp, port, serversocket

I am trying to write a simulator for a hard wired device that acts as a TCP/IP Server.
I have a VB6 Program that conects to this server and communicates however this is failing intermittently and I need to determine what is going wrong so i am writing a program to simulate the server.
I have built the following Java program to listen for a connection from the VB Program and respond with the same information as Server Device would.

```
public class ServerSim {

public static void main(String[] args){
    int port = 23;
    System.out.println("[Listening for Connection]");
    try{
        ServerSocket ss;
        ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        Socket s;

        // The program will wait here until a connection is made.
        s = ss.accept();

        // Print what client we're connected to.
        String client;
        client = s.getInetAddress().toString();
        String localPort = Integer.toString(s.getLocalPort());
        String portNo = Integer.toString(s.getPort());

        System.out.println("[Connected to "+client +"] Port:" + portNo + " localPort: " + localPort);

        //Set up Scanner / Writer to read / write data to client.
        Scanner in;
        //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
        PrintWriter out;
        out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);

        PrintWriter log = openWriter("Log.txt");

        // Establish a 5second connection
        s.setSoTimeout(5000);

        try{
            boolean result = establishConnection(in, out);
            String input = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Recieved: " + input);
            String response = input;
            out.println(response);
            System.out.println("Responded: " + response);
            log.println(input + "->" + response);
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           System.err.println("EXC: "+e.getMessage());                   
           e.printStackTrace();                   
       }
       System.out.println("[Closing Connections]");
       in.close();
        out.close();
        log.close();
        s.close();
        ss.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }        
}
    private static boolean establishConnection(Scanner in, PrintWriter out){
        // we have a connnection - Start by outputtinga  welcome message.       
        out.print("Welcome Session 0\r\n");
        out.flush();            
        out.print("User:\r\n");
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("[Welcome sent - Waiting Response]");
        String input = in.nextLine(); // Recieve the first line.  Should be a User
        System.out.println("[Recieved '"+input+"' - Sending anticipated reply]");
        out.println("Password:");
        input = in.nextLine(); // Recieve the first line.  Should be a User
        System.out.println("[Recieved '"+input+"' - Sending anticipated reply]");
        out.println("User Logged in");      
        return true;
    }
   private static PrintWriter openWriter(String name){
        try{
            File file = new File(name);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                    new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter(file, true)),true);
            return out;
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("I/O Error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

The problem is that the VB<sup>1</sup> Program will not accept the input from my program.

I've compared a network packet capture of a successful device with a capture of the traffic from my own program and everything relevant is the same... *Except* for the reply port.
In My program, the serversocket randomly assigns a port for the response to the VB6 program but when the VB6 program is connected to the physical device I am trying to simulate, the Device only replies on port 1602.

My question is while I am listening to port 23 for a connection (Which is happening fine), how do I get the socket that is created to reply on port 1602 instead of randomly jumping around the 2000 - 3000 mark?

All the replies and questions I can see are around sockets or multithreading without locking the port waiting for a connection.
If this is not a goer, then can someone point me to a better solution for what UI am trying to achieve?
*I know someone will say why not setup a rig with the actual device but they are expensive and I don't have ready access to a spare one for a rig to setup.  That and now that the question has been posed to me, I can't help but find out what is going on! :-)*

<sup>1</sup>
**EDIT:**  I can't interrogate the VB Program as it is using a series of ActiveXs to communicate with the device and handle the protocol.  This is where the issue I am trying to find may be originating so I don't want to write it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reply to the vb-app on port 1602 (and the vb-app doesn't already utilize port 1602 on its side), you'll need another (new) socket.

```
ServerSocket.accept();
```

returns a `java.net.Socket`. This connection is identified by 4 attributes: client-port, client-ip, server-port, server-ip.

It's not the server (your program), which randomly assigns the (what you call) reply-port, it's the client (vb-app). If the client would not do that, the server would not know where it should deliver a response packet.

You may want to create a `java.net.Socket`, with the ip of the vb app and port 1602. It's very likely that the vb-app acts as client *and* server.

Answer (score 0):

Try java.net.Socket .. i am giving you the snippet of my code, which i used to simulate a server running at a specified port. I hope it will be of your use....

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.net.ServerSocket;

import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerTest {

    ServerSocket s;

    public void go() {

        try {
            s = new ServerSocket(44457);

            while (true) {

                Socket incoming = s.accept();
                Thread t = new Thread(new MyCon(incoming));
                t.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    class MyCon implements Runnable {

        Socket incoming;

        public MyCon(Socket incoming) {

            this.incoming = incoming;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(incoming.getOutputStream(),
                        true);
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                        incoming.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String inp = null;

                boolean isDone = true;

                System.out.println("TYPE : BYE");
                System.out.println();
                while (isDone && ((inp = br.readLine()) != null)) {

                    System.out.println(inp);
                    if (inp.trim().equals("BYE")) {
                        System.out
                                .println("THANKS FOR CONNECTING...Bye for now");
                        isDone = false;
                        s.close();
                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                try {
                    s.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ServerTest().go();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "The serversocket randomly assigns a port for the response".

I don't understand that statement. The `Socket` accepted by the `ServerSocket` has a local port number of 23 (same port that the `ServerSocket` is listening on), and a remote port number determined by the client when it connected. This is not under the control of the server program. The device may well only use port 1602 as its outgoing port but the VB program almost certainly lets the operating system decide the port number.

I think you need to re-analyze your observations based on this information.